# Crunch - How to generate specific password list?

Tags: list, passwords, generate, cracking

First Hello! I have a crunch question:

We need to generate some list to crack password which has lower, upper case letters and numbers.
exp: a2jXBv69
We can do it simple way by using "crunch 8 8 abcABC123..." but it will create a huge list with a lot of useless passwords containing only upper case latter or just lower case letters or just numbers which cost a lot of time, power, and its not effective.

Now I didn't find still or I didn't look on right place how to generate only passwords which have upper-lower cases and number without other useless passwords like 214364984941 AIDJFISDOGFJO ssasadasd...

My question need is how to generate a list with only what I need like in this example?

Sorry if you don't understand my English I don't speak or write it very well.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish this would probably be to use a dictionary.
https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords/Common-Credentials

There is no real practical way to "generate" common passwords. Sure there are some tricks, like checking how spellable a word is or adding some numbers e.g. 123 to the end of the password, but they don't nearly produce the same quality passwords as the above-mentioned password list.